# Difference between MongoCursor<Document> vs FindIterable<Document>

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I want know what is the difference between MongoCursor and FindIterable.

**MongoCursor:**

```
MongoCursor<Document> cursorPersonDoc = personDocCollection.find(whereClauseCondition).iterator();
        while (cursorPersonDoc.hasNext()) {
           Document doc = cursorPersonDoc.next();
           String s1 = doc.getString("s1");
         }
```

**FindIterable:**

```
FindIterable<Document> cursorPersonDoc = personDocCollection.find(whereClauseCondition);
    for (doc: cursorPersonDoc){
      String s1 = doc.getString("s1");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the methods which are there in both the classes you will get an idea.

**FindIterable** has methods like  `filter`, `limit`, `skip` which will help you in filtering out the results.
And also it has methods like `maxAwaitTime`(for tailable cursors) and `maxTime`.

**MongoCursor** doesn't have all these. But there is one advantage using MongoCursor. MongoCursor interface extends **`Closeable`**, which in turn extends AutoCloseable.

`AutoCloseable` (introduced in Java 7) makes it possible to use try-with-resources idiom. Something like this

```
try (final MongoCursor cursor = personDocCollection.find(whereClauseCondition).iterator()) {
   ........
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of [findIterable](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) and [mongodbIterable](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoIterable.html)

---

**FindIterable**

Iterable for find.

---

**MongoIterable**

The MongoIterable is the results from an operation, such as a query.

---

`MongoCursor` allow to iterate through any kind of data, since `FindIterable` will iterate through `Find` result only.

`FindIterable` will give you more targeted methods.